# 500 Error being thrown from asmx service and no information in IIS logs

Tags: web-applications, iis-7.5, asmx, application-pool, event-viewer

I have an asmx service which is in constant use, however it randomly returns 500 error to the user.  No error data is returned, just a 500.  There is nothing of interest in the iis logs, however I have found exceptions are unhandled by looking in the event viewer.  There is no commonality as to when the exceptions are thrown, it can be once every 10 minutes, or once every 5 hours and it can occur on any method on the service. The error is thrown, and then the service continues as normal with the next call.

Here is the event log with certain service names etc removed.

The asmx service is not mine, therefore I am unable to rewrite it in a more modern way, so please don't suggest this as a resolution.

````
    <System>
        <Provider Name="ASP.NET 4.0.30319.0" /> 
        <EventID Qualifiers="32768">1309</EventID> 
        <Level>3</Level> 
        <Task>3</Task> 
        <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
        <TimeCreated SystemTime="2020-03-26T09:34:32.000000000Z" /> 
        <EventRecordID>3460784</EventRecordID> 
        <Channel>Application</Channel> 
        <Computer>#####</Computer> 
        <Security /> 
    </System>
    <EventData>
        <Data>3005</Data> 
        <Data>An unhandled exception has occurred.</Data> 
        <Data>3/26/2020 5:34:27 AM</Data> 
        <Data>3/26/2020 9:34:27 AM</Data> 
        <Data>353f04cafe3f4161824279e3093e4c99</Data> 
        <Data>19</Data> 
        <Data>1</Data> 
        <Data>0</Data> 
        <Data>/LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT-1-132296888229654534</Data> 
        <Data>Full</Data> 
        <Data>/</Data> 
        <Data>#####</Data> 
        <Data>#####</Data> 
        <Data /> 
        <Data>10468</Data> 
        <Data>w3wp.exe</Data> 
        <Data>IIS APPPOOL\#####</Data> 
        <Data>HttpUnhandledException</Data> 
        <Data>Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e) at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest() at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) at ASP.defaultwsdlhelpgenerator_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\f29e79a7\3cfe1b87\App_Web_defaultwsdlhelpgenerator.aspx.cdcab7d2.ptsha9ve.0.cs:line 0 at System.Web.Services.Protocols.DocumentationServerProtocol.WriteReturns(Object[] returnValues, Stream outputStream) Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at System.Xml.Schema.Preprocessor.BuildSchemaList(XmlSchema schema) at System.Xml.Schema.Preprocessor.Execute(XmlSchema schema, String targetNamespace, Boolean loadExternals) at System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaSet.PreprocessSchema(XmlSchema& schema, String targetNamespace) at System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaSet.Add(String targetNamespace, XmlSchema schema) at System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaSet.Add(XmlSchema schema) at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSchemas.Compile(ValidationEventHandler handler, Boolean fullCompile) at System.Web.Services.Description.SchemaCompiler.Compile(XmlSchemas schemas) at System.Web.Services.Description.WebServicesInteroperability.AnalyzeDescription(ServiceDescriptionCollection descriptions, BasicProfileViolationCollection violations) at System.Web.Services.Description.WebServicesInteroperability.CheckConformance(WsiProfiles claims, ServiceDescriptionCollection descriptions, BasicProfileViolationCollection violations) at ASP.defaultwsdlhelpgenerator_aspx.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\DefaultWsdlHelpGenerator.aspx:line 1439 at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)</Data> 
        <Data>#####</Data> 
        <Data>#####.asmx</Data> 
        <Data>::1</Data> 
        <Data /> 
        <Data>False</Data> 
        <Data /> 
        <Data>IIS APPPOOL\#####</Data> 
        <Data>12</Data> 
        <Data>IIS APPPOOL\#####</Data> 
        <Data>False</Data> 
        <Data>at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e) at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest() at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) at ASP.defaultwsdlhelpgenerator_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\f29e79a7\3cfe1b87\App_Web_defaultwsdlhelpgenerator.aspx.cdcab7d2.ptsha9ve.0.cs:line 0 at System.Web.Services.Protocols.DocumentationServerProtocol.WriteReturns(Object[] returnValues, Stream outputStream)</Data> 
    </EventData>
</Event>```

Any ideas as to what is causing this would be greatly appreciated.
````

Comment: "No error data is returned, just a 500" is expected, as throwing too much info in error pages is considered to be insecure. "There is nothing of interest in the iis logs" is also expected, as unhandled exceptions are not handled by IIS. "I have found exceptions are unhandled by looking in the event viewer" is correct, as that's where ASP.NET runtime records such. About how to handle such, you might refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/deploying-web-site-projects/processing-unhandled-exceptions-cs

Comment: The issue I have i what is causing the error.  There is no reference to any code which has been written by us, just an issue with the DefaultWsdlHelpGenerator.aspx